# Web Scraping from Amazon website is giving HTTP Error

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nlp

I am using Python: 3.7.1 version and using this, I want to do a web scraping of I-Phone user comments (or Customer Reviews) present in Amazon website (link below).

> Link (to be scraped):
> https://www.amazon.in/Apple-iPhone-Silver-64GB-Storage/dp/B0711T2L8K/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1548335262&sr=1-1&keywords=iphone+X

When I try below code then it is giving me below error:

**CODE:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#import the library used to query a website
import urllib.request         
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

#specify the url
scrap_link = "https://www.amazon.in/Apple-iPhone-Silver-64GB-Storage/dp/B0711T2L8K/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1548335262&sr=1-1&keywords=iphone+X"
wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_state_and_union_territory_capitals_in_India"

#Query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(scrap_link) 
#page = urllib.request.urlopen(wiki) 
print(page)

#Parse the html in the 'page' variable, and store it in Beautiful Soup format
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

print(soup.prettify())
```

**ERROR:**

```
  File "C:\Users\bsrivastava\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Service Unavailable
```

NOTE: When I try to scrape *wiki* link (shown in code) then it is working fine.

So why am I getting this error using Amazon link and how can I overcome it?

---

Also, when I get this Customer Reviews data then I need to store it in a structured format as shown below. How can I do it? ( I am totally new to NLP so need some guidance over here)

```
 Structure:
a. Reviewer’s Name 
b. Date of review 
c. Color 
d. Size 
e. Verified Purchase (True or False) 
f. Rating 
g. Review Title 
h. Review Description
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: Hi, I was trying to do sentiment analysis on this data hence put machine learning by mistake. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 1):

NLP? are you sure?

```
import requests         
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  


scrap_link = "https://www.amazon.in/Apple-iPhone-Silver-64GB-Storage/dp/B0711T2L8K/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1548335262&sr=1-1&keywords=iphone+X"

req = requests.get(scrap_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
container = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'a-section review aok-relative'})
data = []
for x in container:
    ReviewersName = x.find('span', attrs={'class':'a-profile-name'}).text
    data.append({'ReviewersName':ReviewersName})
print(data)
#later save the dictionary to csv
```